# How to update CVS/Root in Eclipse

Tags: cvs

Basically I need to change the username located in the file CVS/Root to a new one to which I have access and each folder has a file like it. Is there a simple way to do this in such a way all folders get updated through CVS or other methods?

Edit: this is in Windows btw. Im not very familiar with ms dos commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transferred all my files in a Unix box and made a script to look for all Root files and substitute all keys with `sed`

```
for file in `find . -name "Root"`; do echo $file; sed -i "s/key1/key2/" $file ; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this just by checking out the code again using the user you have access to. If you have made changes in the code copy them over the top of the fresh checkout.

It is not recommended to edit the CVS metadata.

Comment: Problem is, the root folder names are all different, so CVS thinks this is a new folder for commit.